# Alternative to enrichR for enrichment analysis?

Tags: go-enrichment

I have been using [EdgeR](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/edgeR.html) from the **Bioconductor** package to perform differential expression analysis on bulk RNASeq data sets.

This analysis gives me an output dataframe that has a list of all the genes, ranked by the their adjP values. This dataframe also contains the t-statistic and lfc values for each gene as well.

I have recently been using [enrichR](https://maayanlab.cloud/Enrichr/) to perform gene set enrichment analysis on all the differentially expressed genes to determine what biological, molecular, transcriptional, etc pathways these genes are involved in. I really like the enrichR package for a few key reasons:

1.) It has access to many different databases that I can call on with a simple vector of their names. Most of my data is murine RNASEq, so for those analyses, I can simply select the murine databases:

```
enrichR_dbs <- c("WikiPathways_2019_Mouse", "KEGG_2019_Mouse", "GO_Biological_Process_2018", "GO_Cellular_Component_2018", "GO_Molecular_Function_2018", "GWAS_Catalog_2019", "TRRUST_Transcription_Factors_2019")
```

2.) It uses a single function, enrichR, to perform the enrichment. The arguments for that function are the list of gene symbols and the list of databases.

```
enrichr(as.character(Gene_Dataframe$SYMBOL[1:500]), enrichR_dbs)
```

Anyway, I am looking for another enrichment analysis because I want to be able to see if I get similar pathways for my genes when using another method/algorithm.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find another enrichment analysis( [competitive or self-contained](https://biodatamining.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13040-018-0166-8)) that is both as user-friendly and that gives me easy access to murine databases (without requiring to convert my genes through changes in capitalization, like you need to with GSEA) as enrichR.

**Does anyone have recommendations about enrichment analysis R packages that don't require too many more inputs than the dataframe I generated through my EdgeR analysis?**

P.S. I'm ok with downloading databases if I need to. Though inclusion of a PDF with a tutorial would be fantastic, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of years ago I wrote a blog post about [GSEA methods in Bioconductor](https://b101nfo.blogspot.com/2017/03/gsea-in-bioconductor.html), in addition to these I would recommend [clusterProfiler](https://bioconductor.org/packages/clusterProfiler/) or [ReactomePA](https://bioconductor.org/packages/ReactomePA/).  In most of them you need to provide the gene set/pathway database.
If you want to do gene ontology enrichment then I recomment the [topGO](http://bioconductor.org/packages/topGO/) package.
In most, if not all, of these methods you just need an ordered list and a gene set source.

Answer (score 2):

Try [gProfileR](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gProfileR/versions/0.6.7/topics/gprofiler). It is very intuitive and easy to use in R.